# jquery select all children after nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working with jquery and creating show hide lists, I need hide all the child list items that follow the 6th child in the ul. Normally I would do this by setting the height and then changing the height on click of a click, but for this to work I need to add `overflow:hidden` to my css, and this is not an option.

How would I get all the child list elements that are greater than the 7th child?

Something like,

`$("ul li:6n").domeSomething()`

Answer (score 18):

> How would I get all the child list elements that are greater than the 7th child?

Select the element index = 7+

```
$("ul li:gt(6)").domeSomething()
```

[**`:gt` selector**](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

The selector uses the **zero base index**:

> Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact. This is why $('.myclass:gt(1)') selects elements after the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than after the first. In contrast, :nth-child(n) uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification.

Comment: Actually, your previous `:gt(6)` was right... it starts from the 7th 0-index, which is the same as starting from the 8th child (greater than the 7th child).

Comment: @BoltClock. True, Don't know why I changed it, the 6 in his example confused me.

Comment: Don't worry, it always happens :)

Comment: @BoltClock. Yeah, I hate those indexes... off by one error is the most common error.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to write my answer only to discuss two previous answers: [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967278/315935) from **gdoron** and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967296/315935) from **neu-rah**. If we would see on voting count one can see that the most reader find doron's answer better. I disagree and I try to explanation why.

The explanation you would find the documentation of `:gt()` Selector (see "Additional Notes:" [here](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)):

> Because `:gt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:gt()` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index)` instead.

You can test the code with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wffvm/1/) or better [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/jQueryGtTest1.htm) (with non-minimized code of jQuery 1.7.2). The code use just the statement `$("ul li:gt(6)").css("color", "red");`. You will better understand the problem if you start the demo in Developer Tools of Chrome with **activated button "Pause on exceptions"**. You will see the following exception (it will be not the first one):

[image]

So you can see that the current implementation of jQuery try to use *native* `querySelectorAll()` of the web browser to get the best performance. After that the function [$.makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) will be used to make jQuery wrapper from the `NodeList`. In case of exception [the line](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/1.5.1/sizzle.js#L1189)

```
return oldSizzle(query, context, extra, seed);
```

So you will have the best performance if you would use selectors supported by `querySelectorAll()`. For example

```
$("ul li").slice(7)
```

is better as

```
$("ul li:gt(6)")
```

I would you recommend to use more exact selectors whenever it's possible. For example if the parent `<ul>` element has `id="menu1"` then you can use

```
$("#menu1 >li").slice(7)
```

for the best results. It will help additionally in case of *multiple* `<ul>` elements on your page.

Someone can mention: the selector `"ul li:gt(6)"` works quickly enough. It's correct, but you should don't forget, that you use sometime selectors inside of loop or use it inside of functions which will be called inside of loops. So the difference between 10ms and 30ms can be much more clear if the execution time will be multiplicate to 100.

Moreover it somebody ask yourself the question how to implement some selection and get the answer, he/she will use the code pattern *permanently*. I think that it would be better to use the pattern which has performance advantage. Isn't so.

**UPDATED**: To clear the difference in performance of `$("ul li:gt(6)")`, `$("ul li").slice(7)` and `$("#menu1 >li").slice(7)` selectors I made additionally [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/jQueryGtTest2.htm). Everybody can test the difference in the web browser which he uses. You should additionally not forget, that in case of page having *many other* elements the id selector will work better.

On my computer the execution time of `$("ul li").slice(7)` and `$("#menu1 >li").slice(7)` are about the same (the page have very little elements) and is **about 2.5-4.5 time better** as the for `$("ul li:gt(6)")`. The results can depend on the number of `li` items, the number of elements on the page and many other things, but I hope that the test do clear shown that the usage of `slice` has performance advantage compared with the usage of `:gt` (exactly like we can read in the jqGrid documentation referenced before).

Comment: The selector `"ul li:gt(6)"` works quickly enough. I am terribly sorry, I just had to do it. +1

Comment: @gdoron: The *absolute* time of execution of "ul li:gt(6)" selector is short. I agree, but the execution of `$("ul li").slice(7)` (or if possible `$("#menu1 >li").slice(7)`) will be much better because of **native** web browser code of `querySelectorAll` works quickly as JavaScript code. I wrote at the end of my answer about the case of usage selectors *in the loop*. In the case the difference will be more clear. Old versions of jQuery don't used the code `querySelectorAll`. So there are currently *very much* old best practice examples which used `:eq`, `:first`, `:gt` and so on. It's problem.

Comment: @gdoron: I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/jQueryGtTest2.htm) which shows the performance difference more clear (see UPDATED part of my answer).

Answer (score 2):

use slice to reduce a set

```
.slice(start[,end])
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

example (edited)

```
$("ul li").slice(6).doSomething(...)
```

Comment: What are `start` and `end` supposed to be?

Comment: That's pretty obvious, but what are the values?

Comment: 0 based index, and you can omit end, and you can use negative numbers to select from the end, see link

Comment: If you use `.slice` it needs to be `.slice(7)`. Anyway, this way you select all the `li` just to remove them later...

Comment: +1 from me. I have to write my own answer which explain *why* the way which you suggest is better.

Comment: @gdoron: the implementation of `$("ul li:gt(6)")` is *slowly*. Even `$("ul li").filter(":gt(6)")` which get all `"ul li"` and then filter all with the index `>6`  will be better. The `$("ul li").slice(7)` is just more quick form of `$("ul li").filter(":gt(6)")`. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ul li:eq(6)').nextAll().domeSomething()
```

Comment: Not the way I would use, but if you really want to use it, use this: `$('ul li:eq(7)').nextAll('li').domeSomething()`

Comment: @gdoron If it is valid markup,then no need for specifying 'li'.

Comment: +1, true, didn't thought about it, buy if you want to rely on that, why do you use the `li` in the selector... `;-)`

Comment: @gdoron I have tried to answer by making minimal changes on OP's code ;-)